# PL/pgSQL syntax error at or near "table"

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I've been learning some PL/pgSQL and am having a hard time declaring and using a table type.

I know this script is dumb and doesn't accomplish anything, I'm just trying to learn.

Here is my query:

```sql
do $$
DECLARE
   TYPE employee_collection IS TABLE OF employee%ROWTYPE;
   emp_data employee_collection;
BEGIN
   SELECT * 
   BULK COLLECT INTO emp_data
   FROM employee;
END;
$$
```

When I run this I get this error: `syntax error at or near "TABLE"`.

Everywhere I look online this looks like the way to do this. I even copied most of this code from a website.

Is there a syntax error or is something else going on?

I'm running PostgreSQL 12.11.

Comment: If you're using Postgres, PL/SQL (an Oracle thing) is not something you want to (or can) use. Read the Postgres documentation for the correct Postgres syntax.

Comment: `I even copied most of this code from a website.` - what website - you say "most" - please show us all of this code and the bits you took - if it was an Oracle PL/SQL site, it's hardly surprising that it won't work exactly as is, even though PL/pgSQL is more or less an effort at cloning Oracle's procedural language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PostgreSQL can use PL/**pgSQL**, PL/**Tcl**, PL/**Perl** and PL/**Python**.

PL/SQL is the scripting language used by Oracle Database.
Despite their naming, the two are completely incompatible.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't understand why it was downvoted. I added `LANGUAGE plpgsql` to the end and the error is the same.

Comment: Yes, you will get the same error because the code you posted is ORACLE database PL/SQL and NOT PostgreSQL plpgsql.  Different DBMS, different scripting languages.  The /only/ way that code will work is if you run it in an ORACLE database.  There is no way to make ORACLE PL/SQL work inside PostgreSQL.  
Deliberately misquoted movie time: 
"You must write in pgplsql.  Don't write in PL/SQL and transpose."